# Is it possible to run bandit on a bunch of python files in one folder using command prompt?

Tags: python, bandit-python

I have tried using bandit -r folder/path  it does not seem to work. Any suggestions? Thanks! I am getting all my files skipped for some reason?

```
C:\Users\ablev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310>bandit -r C:\Users\ablev\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 300 6384 Building Secure Python Programs\Bandit Python Test Codes [main]  INFO    profile include tests: None [main]  INFO    profile exclude tests: None [main]  INFO   cli include tests: None [main]  INFO    cli exclude tests: None [main] INFO    running on Python 3.10.1 Run started:2022-02-16 01:50:42.427769

Test results:
        No issues identified.

Code scanned:
        Total lines of code: 0
        Total lines skipped (#nosec): 0

Run metrics:
        Total issues (by severity):
                Undefined: 0
                Low: 0
                Medium: 0
                High: 0
        Total issues (by confidence):
                Undefined: 0
                Low: 0
                Medium: 0
                High: 0 
**Files skipped (9):**
        300 (No such file or directory)
        6384 (No such file or directory)
        Building (No such file or directory)
        C:\Users\ablev\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV (No such file or directory)
        Codes (No such file or directory)
        Programs\Bandit (No such file or directory)
        Python (No such file or directory)
        Secure (No such file or directory)
        Test (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Your `-r` parameter path has a space in it.  You need to surround the whole path in "double quotes".

Comment: Wow, thanks so much!